# Can't get both actions to work in jquery together

Tags: jquery

So, here's the problem.  I wrote a code that opens a div based on the selected dropdown.  That works great.  I then wanted to preselect a specific option ($_POST['value']). That works great.  The problem comes in when I also want to have the correlating div to open as well.  I can do one or the other, but never both together.  Notice that I included the working option and commented it out.  Please show me what I'm supposed to do:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.box').hide();
     $('#sow').change(function() {
        $('.box').hide();
        $('#div' + $(this).val()).show();
     });
   });
  var theText = "Printer Setup";
  //$("#sow option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
  //$("#sow option:contains(" + theText + ")")$('#divoption5').show();
  $("#sow option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected')$('#divoption5').show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `end()` - http://jsfiddle.net/YRJLY/

```
var theText = "Printer Setup";

$("#sow option:contains(" + theText + ")")
    .attr('selected', 'selected')
    .end()
    .find('#divoption5')
    .show();
```

Comment: What do you mean? It's working in JSFiddle. Or you want smth else?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you wanted to do ? (http://jsfiddle.net/ft2PD/13/ shows when the selected item is the one that needs to show the div, http://jsfiddle.net/ft2PD/14/ shows when the selected item should hide the div.

here is the code:

```
<select id='myselect'>
    <option  selected='selected' value='-1'>Please Select </option>
    <option  value='0'>value 0</option>
    <option value='1'>value 1</option>
</select>
<div id='content' style="display:none;">
    content will come here.
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    ShowDiv($('#myselect option:selected'));
    $('#myselect').change(function(){

        ShowDiv(this);
    });

});
function ShowDiv(item)
{
    switch($(item).val())
        {
            case "0":
                $('#content').show();
                break;
            default:
                $('#content').hide();
                break;
        }
}​
```